# 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, list, syntax, attributes

Well I have no idea why it thinks this function variable is a `list`. the problem occurs on line 41 (in the `addPoint()` function)of this code at the time of compilation. I have tried using the `user` global variable in its place and it still does not work. I feel like there is something simple I am missing but cannot pin down.

```
import praw
import time
import re
import pickle
from classes import User



USERAGENT = 'web:CredibilityBot:v0.1 (by /u/ThePeskyWabbit)'
FOOTER = "^^I ^^am ^^a ^^bot! ^^I ^^am ^^currently ^^in ^^test ^^phase. ^^Read ^^about ^^me ^^[here](https://pastebin.com/jb4kBTcS)."
PATH = "C:\\Users\\JoshLaptop\\PycharmProjects\\practice\\commented.txt"

user = User.User("placeholder")
commentFile = open(PATH, 'rb')
commentList = commentFile.read().splitlines()
commentFile.close()

pkl = open("userpkl.pkl", 'rb')
pklList = []

try:
    while(True):
        pklList.append(pickle.load(pkl))
except EOFError:
    pass
pkl.close()

nameList = []
try:
    for data in pklList:
        user = data
        nameList.append(str(user.getName()))
except:
    pass

print(pklList)
print(nameList)


def addPoint(userInstance, comment):
    userInstance.addScore()
    userInstance.addComment(comment)
    message = "Bullshit noted! " + userInstance.getName() + " now has a Bullshit rating of \n\n" + userInstance.getScore() + FOOTER
    return message
```

the class in which that method is written is as follows:

```
import pickle
import praw

class User:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.name = username
        self.bsRating = 0
        self.bsComments = []

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getScore(self):
        return str(self.bsRating)

    def resetScore(self):
        self.bsRating = 0

    def getComments(self):
        return self.bsComments

    def addComment(self, commentLink):
        self.bsComments.append(commentLink)

    def addScore(self):
        self.bsRating = self.bsRating + 1
```

and my error output is:

```
  File "C:/Users/JoshLaptop/PycharmProjects/practice/TestBot.py", line 63, in <module>
    actions = {"!bullshit": addPoint(user, commentLink), "!bullshitrating": getRating(user), "!bullshitdetail":getCommentList(user)}
  File "C:/Users/JoshLaptop/PycharmProjects/practice/TestBot.py", line 41, in addPoint
    userInstance.addScore()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'addScore'
```

Comment: Where are you calling `addPoint` ?

Comment: The error is self explanatory: the first argument you're sending to `addPoint`  is a `list` and a list doesn't have the function `addScore`

Comment: userInstance is not a list. It has no value as it is a placeholder for defining the function

Comment: issue resolved. Was due to `user` being recognized as a list when it was called. Thanks for asking ZdaR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The problem resided in here try:

```
for data in pklList:
    user = data
    nameList.append(str(user.getName()))
except:
    pass
```

by deleted `user = data` and rewriting `user.getName()` as `data.getName()` the problem was resolved. very odd

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like you're writing lots of getters and setters for your object's attributes. This is generally not considered "pythonic": see [this writeup](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/implementing_java-style_getters_and_setters.html) for some discussion on this.

Comment: ah! thank you very much! still learning the nuances of python. Great info